# Ouster of all J**s in California Near

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is "near" an adjective here?  Does "Ouster of all Japs in California Near" mean "Ouster of all Japs in California **Is** Near"? That is, "is" is omitted.

> **Ouster of all Japs in California Near**
> Headlines of newspapers, in stand at 14th and Broadway, presaged on February 27, 1942, the evacuation of persons of Japanese ancestry from military areas.

> Source:  https://www.du.edu/behindbarbedwire/image-48.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Some words are omitted from headlines to save space and allow a larger type size, when the sentence will be understood by native readers. There is no plausible meaning that can be assigned to "California Near" without the "is".

Comment: And note that "ouster" is itself a word you would only see in headlines. (And "Japs" is considered offensive now.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman - and only in American headlines.